# Composition law defined by a map of elements' labels.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let:

- $G$ be a finite set, say $G=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$;
- $I_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$;
- $f\colon I_n \times I_n \rightarrow I_n$ a map.

The composition law:

$$a_ia_j:=a_{f(i,j)}$$

turns $G$ into a group provided that:

i) *closure*: $f(i,j) \in I_n, \forall i,j \in I_n$ - O.K. by definition of $f$;

ii) *associativity*: $f(f(i,j),k)=f(i,f(j,k)), \forall i,j,k \in I_n$;

iii) *unit*: $\exists \bar i \in I_n$ such that $f(\bar i,j)=f(j,\bar i)=j, \forall j \in I_n$;

iv) *inverse elements*: $\forall j \in I_n, \exists k \in I_n$ such that $f(j,k)=f(k,j)=\bar i$.

Given $n$, can we find all the explicit expressions for such an $f$? How does play in this task the (arbitrary) labelling of set's elements?

My attempts go only little farther than $f(i,j):=i+j \mod n$, which gives rise to $\bar i=n$ and $G=\langle a_1 \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Every finite group can be written in this way so there is a surjection from labelled finite groups to the functions you have described. As the function determines the group, finding all such functions for a given $n$ is at least as hard as finding as finding all groups of order $n$ (not generally easy for large $n$).

To describe the function $f$ for a given labelled finite group $G=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ you would define $f(i,j)=k$ such that $a_ia_j=a_k$.

Comment: To my aim, the last sentence ought to be turned the other way around: I'm given a labelled finite *set* (not yet a group) and I want to see whether a certain map of pairs of labels does the job i) to iv). I thought that expressing $f(i,j)$, for fixed $i$ or $j$, in terms of certain permutations of $S_n$ might have assisted to the task past the easiest case (cyclic groups), but I see that this is not the case.

Comment: Do you mean characterise such $f$? In which case you won't find much better than the characterisation that you've given. Following your permutation idea is interesting. Clearly $f(i,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot, j)$ must be permutations. In fact, if $G$ is the group defined by $f$ then these permutations define respectively the left and right actions of $G$ on itself by multiplication. Unfortunately, this is just another way of saying that characterising such $f$ is at least as hard as finding all groups of order $n$.

Comment: I meant more, actually: to give such $f$ explicit expressions. For instance, given an $n$-cycle $\sigma$ and $\bar k \in I_n$, the map $f(\sigma^i(\bar k),\sigma^j(\bar k)):=\sigma^{i+j}(\bar k)$ fulfills the characterisation i) to iv), and indeed shapes the *set* $G=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ into the *group* $G=\langle a_{\sigma(\bar k)}\rangle$, and this holds for every $n$. The next step past cyclicity could be: what's the $f$ for the first noncyclic group, namely Klein 4-group? Or also: what's the $f$ for the first nonabelian group, namely $S_3$?

Comment: Let me put differently the two questions, better fitting my viewpoint: for $n=4$, what's the only other $f$ fulfilling i) to iv)? Then, realize that it defines Klein's 4-group. Likewise for $n=6$ (then, realize that it defines $S_3$).

Comment: You could do take an inductive approach. For brevity I'll just do $n=4$. We can assume $\bar i =1$, so $f(1,i)=i$. Then we look at $f(2,i)$. We'll first choose the inverse. $f(1,2)=2$ so it can't be $1$. At this point $3$ and $4$ are essentially the same so we could choose $f(2,4)=1$ which would lead to the cyclic group. The only choice left is $f(2,2)=1$. $f(2,3)\ne f(1,3)=3$ so the only choice is $f(2,3)=4$. Similarly $f(2,4)=3$. For $f(3,i)$ - we know $2$ and $1$ are not the inverse and if $f(3,4)=1$ we will get the cyclic group, so take $f(3,3)=1$. The rest should follow.

Comment: I ran out of space to do the whole process, but the point is that computing each possible $f(i,\cdot)$ in turn should work, but this process is unsurprisingly long and arduous.

Comment: That' s nice! I find "pedagogical" to show *in this way* that, up to the labelling of set's elements and the choice of the unit, there is just one group of order $4$ other than the cyclic one. Of course group-theoretic approach is by far more elegant (and far reaching!), but this is useful -I think- not to forget that everything virtually comes from what the underlying combinatorics allows or doesn't allow to do. Thank you.